# Map OptionSetType to Array

Tags: swift

Given the following:

```
struct Weekdays: OptionSetType {

    let rawValue: Int
    init(rawValue: Int) { self.rawValue = rawValue }

    static let Monday = Weekdays(rawValue: 1)
    static let Tuesday = Weekdays(rawValue: 2)
    static let Wednesday = Weekdays(rawValue: 4)
    static let Thursday = Weekdays(rawValue: 8)

    static let allOptions: [Weekdays] = [.Monday, .Tuesday, .Wednesday, .Thursday]

}
```

I can convert an array of `Ints` into a `Weekdays` object by doing this:

```
let arr = [1, 4]
let weekdays = arr.reduce(Weekdays()) { $0.union(Weekdays(rawValue: $1)) }
```

My question is, how do I take a `Weekdays` object and convert it into an array of `Ints`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(Not necessarily better, but a different way to look at it and slightly
more general).

`OptionSetType` inherits from `RawRepresentable` and therefore can be
converted from and to the associated raw type, which in your case is
`Int`.

So the "missing link" is a conversion between the raw value (e.g. `5`)
and an integer array of the bitwise components (e.g. `[1, 4]`).

This can be done with an `Int` extension method:

```
extension Int {
    init(bitComponents : [Int]) {
        self = bitComponents.reduce(0, combine: (+))
    }

    func bitComponents() -> [Int] {
        return (0 ..< 8*sizeof(Int)).map( { 1 << $0 }).filter( { self & $0 != 0 } )
    }
}
```

Then your conversion from an array to a `Weekdays` object becomes

```
let arr : [Int] = [1, 4]
let weekdays = Weekdays(rawValue: Int(bitComponents: arr))
print(weekdays)
// app.Weekdays(rawValue: 5)
```

and the reverse conversion

```
let array = weekdays.rawValue.bitComponents()
print(array)
// [1, 4]
```

Advantages:

- The explicit definition of `allOptions:` is not needed.
- It can be applied to other option set types (which have `Int`
  as a raw value).

One could also try to define the conversions as a protocol extension,
e.g. of `IntegerType`, so that the same works with other integer raw types as well. However, this seems to be a bit complicated/ugly
because the left shift operator `<<` is not part of the 
`IntegerType` (or any) protocol.

---

**Update for Swift 3:**

```
extension Int {
    init(bitComponents : [Int]) {
        self = bitComponents.reduce(0, +)
    }

    func bitComponents() -> [Int] {
        return (0 ..< 8*MemoryLayout<Int>.size).map( { 1 << $0 }).filter( { self & $0 != 0 } )
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the fact that allOptions is no longer needed. My solution has one advantage over this one though... My solution can create an array of any type, not just the rawValue type. In my actual use-case, I am mapping from an `OptionSetType` to an array of `Strings`.

That said, your answer covered the specific use-case mentioned in this question very well! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly answering the question, but might be useful to others. Based on Martin's answer I extract back the component objects:

```
extension FixedWidthInteger {
    init(bitComponents : [Self]) {
        self = bitComponents.reduce(0, +)
    }

    var bitComponents : [Self] {
        (0 ..< Self.bitWidth).map { 1 << $0 } .filter { self & $0 != 0 }
    }
}

extension OptionSet where RawValue: FixedWidthInteger, Self == Self.Element {
    var components : [Self] { rawValue.bitComponents.map(Self.init) }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I was writing the question, I figured it out:

```
let array = Weekdays.allOptions.filter { weekdays.contains($0) }.map { $0.rawValue }
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You can improve the context of your extension by defining it conditionally on `OptionSet`.

```swift
extension OptionSet where RawValue: UnsignedInteger {
    var individualCases: [Self] {
        return (0..<(8 * MemoryLayout<RawValue>.size))
            .map { bitsToShift in RawValue(1 << bitsToShift) } // Get every possible single-bit flag
            .filter { (powerOfTwo: RawValue) -> Bool in rawValue & powerOfTwo != 0 } // filter out only the cases the receiver contains
            .map { Self(rawValue: $0) } // create the `OptionSet` (single bit) type
    }
}

let weekdays = Weekdays(rawValue: 0b11111)
weekdays.individualCases.map { $0.rawValue } // [1, 2, 4, 8, 16]
```

A warning: On my 13" 2019 MacBookPro, I had to provide all of the explicit types above to keep the methods type checking under 1500ms in Swift 5.0.

Thanks to [MartinR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31100301/map-optionsettype-to-array#answer-31102661) for the inspiration to loop of the memory layout size.

To complete the example, I've updated the weekday type to Swift 5 below, and  explicitly used the `UInt8` type to make the `individualCases` more efficient. With `UInt`, it would loop over the first `map` and `filter` 64 times each, with `UInt8` it only loops 8 times.

```swift
struct Weekdays: OptionSet {

    let rawValue: UInt8

    static let Monday = Weekdays(rawValue: 1)
    static let Tuesday = Weekdays(rawValue: 2)
    static let Wednesday = Weekdays(rawValue: 4)
    static let Thursday = Weekdays(rawValue: 8)
    static let Friday = Weekdays(rawValue: 16)
}
```